# Malformed Cookie error after bundling Angular with MVC 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angularjs

I have an MVC5 project that I am using angular with and getting the following error:

```
Error: malformed URI sequence
oh/h.cookies@https://controlpanel.abc.com/bundles/controlPanelAngularv=c7IsPcEqfC9w7vlO0f2C635w9XFObG3zp4KjeFBEh-c1:1:18254
g@https://controlpanel.abc.com/bundles/controlPanelAngular?v=c7IsPcEqfC9w7vlO0f2C635w9XFObG3zp4KjeFBEh-c1:1:35522
k/s<@https://controlpanel.abc.com/bundles/controlPanelAngular?v=c7IsPcEqfC9w7vlO0f2C635w9XFObG3zp4KjeFBEh-c1:1:34445
de/u/h.promise.then/c@https://controlpanel.abc.com/bundles/controlPanelAngular?v=c7IsPcEqfC9w7vlO0f2C635w9XFObG3zp4KjeFBEh-c1:1:48272
```

This error only happens when the website is deployed and in production.

I think it has something to do with the way .net bundles things but I'm not certain.

My bundle looks like:

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/controlPanelAngular").Include(
  "~/Scripts/angular/dist/angular.min.js",
  "~/Scripts/angular/dist/ui-bootstrap-angular.min.js",
  "~/Scripts/angular/dist/master.js"
));
```

Where `master.js` is my concatenated file of my app ( built using `grunt` ). I don't understand the bundling process well enough to even know where to look. I've read the documentation on the process, but it doesn't offer any help on this type of issue. The only issues I can find on google that people are having is that their angular isn't "minification friendly", but mine is. I used the **inline syntax** `(angular.module('module').controller('ctrl', ['$injector', function($injector))` so its not that.

My code does not use `decodeURIComponent`, `encodeURIComponent`, angular routing service, `html5Mode`, `$location`, cookies, or anything I can think of that would cause this error. I do have a navigation service that gets called a couple of times:

```
angular.module('core.service').factory('navigatorService', ['$window', function ($window) {
  return {
    redirect: function (newLocation) {
      $window.location.href = newLocation;
    }
  };
}]);
```

This is the only time I even access the url. There are no url parameters that I use. There is one page where I even need one, but due to the way MVC builds url's I passed it in through the `@ViewBag` instead of messing with parsing it in angular:

```
ng-init="init(@(ViewBag.categoryId));"
```

The architect of the project wants us all to use the asp actions to generate urls so that if the location changes our url's get updated.

An inline factory was created to do so:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
angular.module('core.service').factory('mvcRouterService', function () {
    return {
        getCategoryUrl: function () { return '@Url.Action("GetCategory", "Categories")'; }
    };
});
</script>
```

This is what I use to build all of my url's for ajax calls.

Used like:

```
angular.module('module').factory('genericAjax', ['$http', '$injector', function ($http, $injector) {
  var mvcRouterService = $injector.get('mvcRouterService');
    return {
      getCategory: function (categoryId) {
        var data = {
          categoryId: categoryId
        };
      return $http.post(mvcRouterService.getCategoryUrl(), data).then(function (result) {
        return result.data;
      });
    }
   };
 }]);
```

I also found several links talking about an issue that seems similar to this:

https://github.com/ivpusic/angular-cookie/issues/28

But those were from a year ago and fixes have been merged in by now.

Also if I copy and paste any of those urls from the @ part on, they all resolve in the browser, if that matters

I unminified all the files and got a more accurate stack trace, still can't figure out what could be causing this:

```
"Error: malformed URI sequence
Browser/self.cookies@https://controlpanel.abc.com/Scripts/angular/dist/angular.js:4811:33
sendReq@https://controlpanel.abc.com/Scripts/angular/dist/angular.js:8813:1
$http/serverRequest@https://controlpanel.abc.com/Scripts/angular/dist/angular.js:8539:25
processQueue@https://controlpanel.abc.com/Scripts/angular/dist/angular.js:12078:25
scheduleProcessQueue/<@https://controlpanel.abc.com/Scripts/angular/dist/angular.js:12094:36
 $RootScopeProvider/this.$get</Scope.prototype.$eval@https://controlpanel.abc.com/Scripts/angular/dist/angular.js:13278:25
$RootScopeProvider/this.$get</Scope.prototype.$digest@https://controlpanel.abc.com/Scripts/angular/dist/angular.js:13090:37
$RootScopeProvider/this.$get</Scope.prototype.$apply@https://controlpanel.abc.com/Scripts/angular/dist/angular.js:13382:33
bootstrapApply@https://controlpanel.abc.com/Scripts/angular/dist/angular.js:1494:20
invoke@https://controlpanel.abc.com/Scripts/angular/dist/angular.js:4101:17
bootstrap/doBootstrap@https://controlpanel.abc.com/Scripts/angular/dist/angular.js:1493:25
bootstrap@https://controlpanel.abc.com/Scripts/angular/dist/angular.js:1512:13
angularInit@https://controlpanel.abc.com/Scripts/angular/dist/angular.js:1406:45
@https://controlpanel.abc.com/Scripts/angular/dist/angular.js:24416:9
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anybody is curious I added a try catch to the angular code around where it was erroring and ajaxed the error to try and track down a more specific error. I ended up finding out that the malformed cookie was a google analytics cookie on a few of our users pc's. Not sure why angular was unable to handle the error. It was the _utmz cookie

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/cookie-usage